# How to increase mouse scroll wheel speed in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, mousewheel

Loving the switch from Eclipse to NetBeans. Anyone know how to increase the number of lines scrolled using the mouse wheel in the editor window?  Currently it only goes one at a time -- i'd like it to do at least three.

Comment: I suppose I'll have to compile my own netbeans... hoping this isn't the answer.

Comment: I should note that this is on OSX Leopard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm struggling with this on Mac OS X, snow leopard, with a Microsoft mouse and IntelliPoint 7.1, and NetBeans 6.8. Vertical scroll settings work well in other apps, such as Firefox, but Netbeans only scrolls one line per mouse wheel click.

Comment: Upgrading to snow leopard has solved my mouse wheel scroll issues.

Answer (score 2):

NetBeans picks up the number of lines to scroll from the OS.

On XP you set the number of lines to scroll with `Control Panel > Mouse > Wheel > Scrolling`

On KDE, its `System Settings > Keyboard and Mouse > Mouse > Advanced`.

I assume there is something similar for Gnome, but I don't see it off hand.

Comment: No, it doesn't respect OSX settings.

Answer (score 1):

Same issues here on Mac OSX 10.5.8 with Logitech Mouse (LX3). Other apps are working with OS settings, only Netbeans seems to ignore them.